# How can we use loop to take multiple input in php? What is wrong with this program?

Tags: php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="number" name="x" value="0"/>
<input type="number" name="y"/>
<input type="number" name="z"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$x=$POST_['x'];
$y=$POST_['y'];
$z=$POST_['z'];
echo $x;
echo $y;
echo $z;
?>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?
I'm trying to take input from user and print it. I have done this manually but this is also not running.

Comment: `$_POST` is one issue

Comment: You echo AFTER the end of `</html>`. That won't work!

Comment: And like pavneet says, it's `$_POST`, not `$POST`

Comment: What do loops have to do with this?  You have a couple of typo mistakes (pointed out in other comments), but aside from that it's not clear what you're even asking.

Comment: Why do you want to take values out of a perfectly good array `$_POST` anyway. What is the point

Comment: I *presume* you want to do something to output each input and you've dropped the (faulty) manual echoes in as a test... try something along the lines of `<?php foreach($_POST as $key => $value): ?><li><?= $key; ?> -> <?= $value; ?></li><?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: I have taken the input three times and I want to do it using loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 issues with your code.

1. Move your PHP inside the `body` tag - it *will* work as is, but you *shouldn't* do it because there is a risk of writing characters after that closing tag which should be the last thing in the output.
2. Change `$POST` to `$_POST`
3. Wrap the output in an **if statement**, to ensure something has been posted (or you'll receive an undefined index error.)

If you want to use the values of the inputs in a loop (so you don't have to manually specify each one), you could try the following.

```php
<?php
  foreach($_POST as $input){
      echo $input . "<br>";
  }
?>
```

**Further Readings**
If you're just leaning, you can find some information regarding forms [on the PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

The snippet below won't actually work here on SO - just added it for reference.

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="x" value="0" />
    <input type="number" name="y" />
    <input type="number" name="z" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  
  <!-- OR -->
  
  <?php
  $fields = ['a' => '0', 'b' => '', 'c' => '']
  
  foreach($fields as $name => $value){
    echo "<input type='number' name='" . $name . "' value='" . $value . "'/>
  }
  
  ?>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    $x= $_POST['x'];
    $y= $_POST['y'];
    $z= $_POST['z'];
    echo $x;
    echo $y;
    echo $z;
  }
  
  // OR
  foreach($_POST as $input){
      echo $input . "<br>";
  }
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `if ($_POST)` is not the best, consider using `isset` and `empty` with `trim`.

Comment: Thanks, can we take input only once using loop and array?

Comment: @Wiz that's the `foreach` part at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: No, `if ($_POST)` doesn't determine if something has been posted, it determines if keys exist in `$_POST` by true / false. If you want to check the incoming request purely use `filter_has_var` with `INPUT_POST`.

Comment: @Script47 Yeah, I realised I was talking rubbish immediately after I posted the comment. It's been removed.

Comment: Can we also use loop in the form?

Comment: @Wiz Yes, I have updated my answer (this time). However, for any further inquiries, consider opening a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Move your PHP output to inside the `<body>`. Change `$POST_` to `$_POST`. Set a default if the field wasn't posted.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="x" value="0"/>
    <input type="number" name="y"/>
    <input type="number" name="z"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
    $x = isset($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] : '';
    $y = isset($_POST['y']) ? $_POST['y'] : '';
    $z = isset($_POST['z']) ? $_POST['z'] : '';
    echo $x;
    echo $y;
    echo $z;
?>
```

To do it in a LOOP, do this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // key is x, y, or z
    // value is the value of x, y, or z
}
```

Comment: lol that's not nice, people gotta start somewhere! :-P

Comment: I was not trying to be nasty, apologise. Been looking for an excuse to use the `Plonker` comment for days now :) :)

Comment: ah lol, only fools and horses haha. carry on!

Comment: Personally, I'd use this solution purely because of the explicit `isset` checks on each variable.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you just want to do a simple dump of your form values into the HTML page after submission - in a loop (I've fixed the `$POST_` typos):

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="number" name="x" value="0"/>
<input type="number" name="y"/>
<input type="number" name="z"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<!-- using PHP in templating style -->
<!-- check to see if the form has been posted -->
<?php if(!empty($_POST)): ?>
<ul>
<!-- loop through the posted inputs -->
<?php foreach($_POST as $key => $value): ?>
<li><?= $key; ?> -&gt; <?= $value; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Or you could use something like `<pre><?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>` if it's just debugging output.